# Help finding the critical values of α where the qualitative nature of the phase portrait for the system changes?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, eigenfunctions

I was asked to solved for the eigenvalues in terms of α for 2X2 matrix and so i did and my answer was marked as correct. Then I was asked to solve for this:

The roots are complex when?

There is a saddle point for?

The equilibrium point is a stable node where?

I tried solving the problem by finding values which would give me 1 and zero for the eigenvalues and got the values of -24/11, -25/11 and -26/11 but the were all wrong. How would i solve for these three questions? 
can someone walk me through the steps?

The eigenvalues in terms of α are:

$r = -1 + \dfrac{\sqrt{100 + 44 \alpha}}{2}$

$r_2 = -1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{100 + 44 \alpha}}{2}$

Comment: The roots are complex when $100+44\alpha<0$, i.e. when $\alpha<-\frac{25}{11}$. There is a saddle point when the eigenvalues are real and have opposite sign, so you need $r_1>0$ and $r_2<0$, hence $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{100+44\alpha}>1$, so $\sqrt{100+44\alpha}>2$, so $100+44\alpha>4$, so $\alpha>-\frac{24}{11}$. A stable node occurs when both roots are negative but real, so $r_1<0$ and $r_2<0$, which happens when $-\frac{25}{11}<\alpha<-\frac{24}{11}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! you made me realize that i had forgotten to enter the alpha <, and alpha is >

Answer (score 1):

**symplectomorphic:**

- The roots are complex when $100+44α<0$, i.e. when $α<−\frac{25}{11}$.
- There is a saddle point when the eigenvalues are real and have opposite sign, so you need $r_1>0$ and $r_2<0$, hence $\frac12\sqrt{100+44α}>1$, so $100+44α>4$, so $α>−\frac{24}{11}$.
- A stable node occurs when both roots are negative but real, so $r_1<0$ and $r_2<0$, which happens when $−\frac{25}{11}<α<−\frac{24}{11}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Viete's formula to determine the sign of $\alpha$: 
so you will have: 
$r_1  + r_2 = -2$ and $r_1 * r_2 = 1 - A*(2+A)$ where $A = \frac{(100 + 44 \alpha)^{1/2}}{2}$

Comment: The last is wrong, as $(-1-A)(-1+A)=1-A^2$ by binomial formula.